# rhythmbox unstable after pause/play from python script

Tags: python-3.x, rhythmbox

I have a python gtk interface that pause rhythmbox with rhythmbox-client --pause, play a video and after that play again rhythmbox with rhythmbox-client --play

The problem is that sometimes rhythmbox after the unpause, begin to be unstable: the sound stops (but the interface continue running the song), the seconds show incoherent data (like 4322346234:12)...

I have tried different method to call rhythmbox-client inside the python script: os.system, subprocess.run, subprocess.call all with the same result.

any idea what could be the problem? Btw, rhythmbox vers. 3.2.1 and python 3.5.1

Comment: "I have a python gtk interface" Okay, so then is there a reason why you're not using MPRIS?

Comment: Really, I didn't know it is so easy to use mpris. But the problem persist... the pause/play works from the python script but rhythmbox stops playing some seconds after the replay (and the interface continue counting the song time). Seems a rhythmbox bug to me....

Comment: Workaround: It seems that the problem goes away when disable the Crossfade between tracks in preferences.